# Issues with API in Volley

Tags: android, android-volley, postman

I am able to make successful request from postman but unable to make successful request using volley in android studio

Following are screenshots of postman request body and header
[image]

[image]

Following is my volley code

```
val API = "https://carenextion.org/api/v1/care_team"
val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@ActivityAddCareTeam)
        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            API,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                val json = JSONObject(response)
                Log.i("response", response)
                if (json.getBoolean("success")) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@ActivityAddCareTeam, "Care team added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    finish()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@ActivityAddCareTeam, "There was an error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                Toast.makeText(this@ActivityAddCareTeam, "There was an error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }) {

            override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params["title"] = teamName
                params["description"] = teamDescription
                params["gender"] = gender
                params["location"] = teamLocation
                params["age_range"] = ageRange
                return params
            }

            override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                headers["Authorization"] = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo0MDA2LCJleHAiOjE1NTc2NzMyNTd9.4y87SG57cbjgh6oo8VQizZsOml-QupE4n4ywD0EUxT4"
                return headers
            }
        }
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest)
```

I get following response in postman

```
{
"success": true,
"user": {
    "id": 342,
    "title": "demo",
    "gender": "male",
    "description": "test desc",
    "age_range": "55-64"
},
"message": "CareTeam Added"
```

}

but in volley, I get following

```
{"success":false,"error":{"code":999,"message":"undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass"}}
```

Comment: from the first look, I would check if volley sends the params as array or as 5 independent params. I haven't used Volley for a while, but try to find a way to get the network traffic  into your log, so you can see what really(!) gets send to the server.

Comment: @muetzenflo thanks for replying, let me see if I get get traffic info

Comment: can you try volley JSON request instead of string request?

Comment: Thanks @AsadChoudhary for commenting, according to my knowledge, we can use only string request to pass params to a server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code for `getParams()`

```
override fun getParams(): MutableMap<String, String> {
            val params = HashMap<String, String>()
            params["care_team[title]"] = teamName
            params["care_team[description]"] = teamDescription
            params["care_team[gender]"] = gender
            params["care_team[location]"] = teamLocation
            params["care_team[age_range]"] = ageRange
            return params
        }
```